# How to get gradle exec task to print std out in real-time

Tags: gradle, npm, build.gradle, angular-cli

I am executing a gradle exec task to build npm:

```
task build(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "npm","run", "build"
}
```

However, it only prints all of the standard output from `npm run build` when the task is completed. Whereas if you run it manually, it prints stuff to std out as it is running.

How do I get the std out to print in real-time?